# Inline Block Elements not align horizontally

Tags: css, wordpress, input

This is for a form in a test site which isn't aligning (horizontal) properly. Check the form under the div#search-bar

http://dev.websuccess.solutions/tntbuyshomes/

If you inspect element under , I have made these

```
div.nf-field-container {
   width: 201px;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0px 2.5px 0px 2.5px; }
```

But it is still not aligning. I have tried vertical-align:top as well but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
nf-fields-wrap {
   display: flex;
}

nf-field {
   display: block;
}
```